# select data from one table, check against and pull values from second table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a sql query like below, which is selecting values based on if they exist in the questions table and their section_id value falls within a certain range,

```
SELECT action_id, action_type, action_details, action_int, action_time
        FROM actions
        WHERE user_id = '".$id."'
        AND action_type = 'other'
        AND ( action_details = 'random question'
                OR action_details = 'review')
        AND action_int IN (
            SELECT id
            FROM questions
            WHERE section_id IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8) )
```

And I want to expand it to also pull a second column value from the questions table, 'section_id', and join it onto the results.

What is the best way to go about this?
Thanks

Comment: So, what's going wrong with the query you posted?

Comment: it doesn't have the section_id value in the output array. It just check to make sure action_int equals an id(in questions table) which falls in the section_id = 2-8 range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your use of in in the section_id I believe this left join should work:

```
SELECT a.action_id, a.action_type, a.action_details, a.action_int, a.action_time, q.section_id 
FROM actions a left join questions q on a.action_int = q.id 
WHERE a.user_id = '".$id."'
    AND a.action_type = 'other'
    AND a.action_details in('random question', 'review') 
    AND q.section_id IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your code, I am assuming the actions.action_int field correlates to the questions.id field, and I believe this is what you're asking for:

`SELECT actions.action_id, actions.action_type, actions.action_details, actions.action_int, actions.action_time, questions.section_id

        FROM actions

        JOIN questions

        ON actions.action_int = questions.id

        WHERE user_id = '".$id."'

        AND action_type = 'other'

        AND ( action_details = 'random question'

                OR action_details = 'review')

        AND action_int IN (

            SELECT id

            FROM questions

            WHERE section_id IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8) )`